# The approaches to using SVG images

Tags: html, css, svg

I've just read [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/images/use-icons?hl=en) from Google Web Fundamentals on using SVG for icons. Two approaches are given. The first is the inline approach. For example:

```
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path d="M27 4l-15 15-7-7-5 5 12 12 20-20z" fill="#000000"></path>
  </svg>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsaabuvx/)

The second approach is to use an image tag such as: `<img src="credit.svg">`

I'm also aware SVGs can be defined as:

- an object
- an embed tag
- an iframe

They can also be set as background images in CSS.

**My question:**

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, should you be worrying about who's looking at your code? SVG inline will always bloat your HTML depending how complex the drawn SVG is. Inline does in some respect have better performance implications due to the fact it's being loaded directly with the HTML as opposed to loading the SVG externally when using it, for example, as an `<img>`. However, it's practically unnoticeable and should be the least priority when coming down to performance.

### The disadvantages of inline SVG:

- Bloats code
- Cannot be cached by the browser
- No fallback available
- IE, without XHTML (and that's if SVG is supported) doesn't support SVG **technically**, though this is a low priority and we shouldn't care about it in the current world of the web. Still, it's primarily a disadvantage to those ancient warriors.

### The advantages of inline SVG:

- I can't think of any, seriously. Other nosey people can see it?
- Actually, **those without CSS enabled can see it**.

### The disadvantages of using `<img>` with SVG:

- Again, limited fallback support (You can use Modernizr to replace the `.svg` extension with `.png`, but then you rely on the user having javascript enabled)
- Limited styling options with the SVG

### The advantages of using `<img>` with SVG:

- Semantically better than bloating all your code
- Readability in your codebase is better for a) yourself and b) other developers who might be working on the project too.
- Better maintainability.

### Alternative methods:

You can use the following methods you provided in your question (and below) about using `<object>`, `<embed>` and `<iframe>`, although, these also limit the use cases and would need declaring in **every** HTML document, which can get messy as you progress in a project, whether it be large or small.

### The 'better approach':

Disclaimer: By no means is the a 'better for everyone' method. This is simply how I would declare my SVG elements for **reusability** and gives me **full** control of identifying my assets when using SVG.

The biggest pitfall for using inline SVG in your HTML is the fallback support. I have always used SVG as a background image (unless it's a webfont I'm using for icons etc.), purely because I can create a `.png` version and write the fallback in my CSS, like so:

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
}

.icon--16 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

/* Always declare the PNG before the SVG. */
.icon--foo-blue {
    background-image: url('foo-blue.png'); /* Fallback */
    background-image: url('foo-blue.svg'), none; /* Modern */
}

.icon--foo-green {
    background-image: url('foo-green.png'); /* Fallback */
    background-image: url('foo-green.svg'), none; /* Modern */
}
```

Then, use it:

```
<span class="icon icon--16 icon--foo-blue"></span>
<span class="icon icon--16 icon--foo-green"></span>
```

### The disadvantage of this:

- No support for CSS styling, however, we should be aware of why we are styling SVG in our CSS. If you're using more colours than your website uses then there is generally something not right. Declaring 4 files for the same SVG but in a different colour is **not** bad practise as it allows us to cache these in the browser for later, throughout **any** webpage which in the answer constructed below completely removes this purpose. Take advantage of caching on the server/within the browser!

And of course, it depends what kind of image you are trying to render to the user. If you're going to use large SVG files for showcasing something, for example, I would probably think about what kind of users I'm targeting; that being, those on modern browsers because I might want to include fancy inline SVG animations etc.

It really depends on personal preference too. There is no major red flags for using SVG inline to this day, but we still have some heart for those back in the stone ages of less-than IE9. And, not to forget, Android is quirky with SVG too!

**EDIT**: It seems like there is a large debate over inline SVG's. One word of warning is, there is no reusability doing this. If you're showcasing a fancy website with fancy SVG animations, then by all means, build your entire page in SVG for crying out loud. No one is stopping you. It's personal preference. But for icons, where you will more than likely reuse throughout a project, please, declare them outside your HTML as it gives you **greater control in the long run** and not because you need a different colour here and there. Think about it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer - I've also amened the question to consider defining SVGs as objects, iframes and embed tags. Also mentioned CSS background images (as you've already pointed out as a good approach in your answer)

Comment: This is absolutely bad and backward approach to use SVG as background — try to set color for your icons, huh? For example, I have one icon in three different places on my web page and it should be colored differently — how you make this? I will answer for you — you are just copy/paste one icon three times and set color for each icon. And now you have three absolutely equal icons with only fill color different. Great job!

Comment: "IE, without XHTML" — oh, c'mon, when ever will you use anything different of <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: @artuska You missed the point about "fallback" support, unless of course, you're using CSS to mask PNG colours too. Learn your roots boy.

Comment: For you, your knowledge on working within a needy clientele-based environment is shockingly poor. That is possibly the worst Grunt method for spitting out PNG/SVG declarations I've __ever__ seen in terms of reusability and scalability.

Comment: Your answer about SVG shows you know nothing about SVG. And, yes, this is absolutely good Grunt plugin — also, we are talking about fallback possibilities in inline SVG, not the Grunt plugins, right?

Comment: You did not answered anything about icon reusability on your web page — when you need one icon to be placed in 20 different places with 20 different colors and outlines.

Comment: A question regarding "Android is quirky with SVG too", do you mean the native Android browser (Chrome)?

Comment: @henrywright sorry, I should've mentioned version 4.3 and lower with the native browser. It's supported, but weird in rendering sometimes. Only 4.4 (KitKat) now includes Chrome by default (which is fine with SVG, 100% supported). Basic support is still pretty good however. :)

Comment: sorry, last question - which browsers or browser versions would suffer if I didn't provide fall-back support?

Comment: Anything less than IE9 and Android 4.3 & less have limited support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Thanks for the link to caniuse. Very useful!

Comment: It is 2022. A modern Web Component ``<load-svg>``, supported in all browsers. Can do the job: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Answer (score 4):

### The advantages of using `img`, `object`, `embed` and other with SVG backgound:

- `<img class="icon icon_foo">` is much shorter and beautiful than inline SVG — `<svg class="icon icon_foo"><use xlink:href="#foo"></use></svg>`

### The disadvantages of using `img`, `object`, `embed` and other with SVG backgound:

- you absolutely have no any control of styling options — you cannot set color, outline width and outline color — all you can do is just to put SVG as background and set styles right in SVG file one time
- you cannot reuse your icons because of statement above (if you have one icon in two-three-twenty different places on your web page and it should be colored in different colors the only way is to create two-three-twenty equal SVG files with only one difference — fill option ;)

### The advantages of using inline SVG:

- reusability (eg. you have only one Twitter SVG icon and you can use it everywhere with any styles, so, you do not need 2 or 3 same SVG files just with different fill attribute in each SVG file)
- complete control over your icon appearance — styles, colors, sizes

### The disadvantages of using inline SVG:

- it is longer than IMG and does not look beautiful

### Caching:

**Using AngularJS or any other framework:**

```
<ng-include src="'icons.html'"></ng-include>
```

**Using VanillaJS:**

```
file icons.js on your server:

var icons = '<svg><symbol id="icon-XXX" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><path d="{here_goes_compounded_path}"></path></symbol></svg>';

in HEAD section:

<script src="icons.js"></script>

<script>
    document.getElementById('icon-placeholder').innerHTML(icons);
</script>

right after the BODY tag:

<div id="icon-placeholder" style="display:none;"></div>
```

---

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u15p8217/1/) with the best approach:

Right after *body* tag place all your SVG icons (or use Angular's or any other framework ng-include):

```
<body>
    <svg style="display:none;">
        <symbol id="icon-XXX" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><path d="{here_goes_compounded_path}"></path></symbol>
        <symbol id="icon-YYY" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><path d="{here_goes_compounded_path}"></path></symbol>
    </svg>
```

In any place on your web page put an icon:

```
<svg class="icon icon_red">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-XXX"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="icon icon_green">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-YYY"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="icon icon_blue">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-XXX"></use>
</svg>
```

In CSS:

```
.icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    fill: currentColor;
}
.icon_red { fill: #f00; }
.icon_green { fill: #0f0; }
.icon_blue { fill: #00f; }

.icon_foo {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 8;
    fill: #0f0;
}
```

Do not forget about magic "currentColor" CSS variable — it will color your SVG icon in current text color:

```
fill: currentColor;
```

---

### Further must read:

- any front-end RSS feeds: inline SVG is about a year old discussion
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/27/svg-icons-ftw/
- http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveSVGs/index.html
- http://ianfeather.co.uk/ten-reasons-we-switched-from-an-icon-font-to-svg/

Comment: thanks for this answer. What's the advantage of using your approach over the rest of the approaches I mention? for example, using the <object> tag to display SVG images

Comment: I can modify icon with CSS classes as I wish — colorize it or make any outline size and color I want. You cannot achieve this by using SVG in background.

Comment: Also, this is the very modern way to use SVG at the moment.

Comment: Why ever you want to use <object> for icons? This is totally the same as <img>.

Comment: That's my question! I'm not saying I want to use <object>. I'm asking why, or why not, to use it

Comment: Because it is the same as using <img>, <span>, <div>, <p>, <place_any_other_tag_here> — you can only place SVG icon on background in these elements and you will never have control over it's color or outline size/color.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still slightly confused. see the sub-section Which Should You Use? in this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/) - it recommends the use of <object>

Comment: The one and the only reason anybody saying about <img> or <object> is to make your HTML code shorter. Because inline SVG is long an looks «ugly» they say.

Comment: Then you need to ask yourself, **why** do I need to have anything more than two colours on any given image? Unless you're colouring in a a child's colouring book, you shouldn't need to under at any point. If you are colouring in a child's colouring book, then you should be using inline `fill` declarations, **inline** of the SVG. You're just escalating a case-use that is unrealistic. Who on earth is going to declare **all** of their SVG in the top of their `<body>` for **every** single page? Even on small projects, this is totally abundant and dissolving the use of performance. Caching, anyone?

Comment: Also, how will I re-use these SVG's when I want a new page, **unless** I'm using something such as AngularJS, or Twig etc? Too many one-page website solutions here and not enough reusability unfortunately. I provided a reusable scenario, where my images, for example, would only have a range of colours that would be re-used throughout an entire site. If I need two colours, I'll have two files. Simple. Learn the difference between **abstraction and separations of concern**.

Comment: This is under the pre-assumption the developer **has** to develop with AngularJS and/or use JavaScript, right? This is completely off-topic from the question.

Comment: AngularJs is just an example, I have also provided VanillaJS as you can see with your eyes.

Comment: "This is under the pre-assumption the developer has to develop with AngularJS **and/or use Javascript**" and still doesn't answer the deviation of developing more than a one-page website which I'm sure many people **don't do**.

Comment: There is a title called «Caching» — all those methods are perfectly cached by browser, works in any browser and good for single page and multipage web site.

Comment: I still don't believe the solution to SVG, whether in the past or future, is by declaring them directly inline of my HTML when and where I may need them. This seems extremely off-piste when developing. I'd like to see websites that use this method proficiently if you have any examples?

Comment: Looking through Google's docs (not sure if they can be used as an example of good practice?) [this page](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) uses the `img` tag.

Comment: http://ianfeather.co.uk/ten-reasons-we-switched-from-an-icon-font-to-svg/ — well, everyone is using inline SVG if they are making modern web site (of course Google does not, they are still using PNG sprites 'cos it is impossible just to remake everything they do)

Comment: And, yes, it is not past — it is future :)

Comment: One thing that I think isn't strictly true, is the bit about the object tag and styling. You can style indirectly, change attributes etc on the fly (eg you can use it to animate your SVG) as its accessible via the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

What I tend to do nowadays is wrap it inside a Web Component:

`/assets/svg/hex.js`

```js
export default `<svg>...</svg>`;
```

`/my-svg.js`

```js
class MySvg extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const id = this.getAttribute('id');
    import(`./assets/svg/${id}.js`).then(svg => {
      this.innerHTML = `
        ${svg.default}
      `;
    });
  }
}
customElements.define("my-svg", MySvg);
```

`index.html`

```html
<my-svg id="hex"></my-svg>
```

This way I get the advantages of inline svg, lazy loading due to dynamic import and without the bloat in the code I'm supposed to work on / maintain, with just one custom element. And the id attribute makes clear which svg I'm loading.